# Vue js the field in data() was not initialized by call of second (help) function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, methods, frontend

I don't have almost any experience with vue js.

I have 2 functions `loadComponentsOfUser()` and `loadUserId()`, so that loadComponentsOfUser() uses the userID field, which must be loaded by the loadUserId() function.

```js
data() {
  return { 
    userId: ''
  }
},

created() {
  this.loadComponentsOfUser()
},

methods(): {
   loadUserId() {
       axios.get('getUserId').then(res => {
            this.userId = res.data
        }).catch(() => {
            ...
            })
        });
     },
     loadComponentsOfUser() {
         this.loadUserId()
         axios.get('users/' + this.userId).then(res => {
         }).catch(() => {
             ...
             })
         });
}
```

The loadUserId() function works correctly and loads the correct value from the server

But when loadComponentsOfUser() is called, the this.userId field looks like it has not been initialized and an empty field comes to the axios.

my question is why the field was not initialized after calling loadUserId()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for responses, yo can use `async` and `await`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return { 
      id: 1,
      userId: '',
      user: null
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.loadComponentsOfUser()
  },
  methods: {
    async loadUserId() {
       await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + this.id)
         .then((res) => {
           this.userId = res.data.id
         })
         .catch(() => {})
    },
    async loadComponentsOfUser() {
      await this.loadUserId()
      if(this.userId) {
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + this.userId)
          .then(res => {
            this.user = res.data
          })
          .catch(() => {})
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.27.2/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-odNmoc1XJy5x1TMVMdC7EMs3IVdItLPlCeL5vSUPN2llYKMJ2eByTTAIiiuqLg+GdNr9hF6z81p27DArRFKT7A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <input type="number" v-model="id" /><button @click="loadComponentsOfUser">load</button>
  {{ user }}
</div>
```